# Menu nav dropdown links don't work on home nav only

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, wpbakery

Site I did not build but trying to help with, recently, (don't recall it being an issue before so maybe some update jacked it up?) no longer shows the hover on the drop downs of the links from the home page, thus also is not clickable. The top nav links are but the subpages/dropdowns do not.

However, if you click to another page, they do.

I did see in another question about adding the following CSS

```
nav ul.main-menu {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

of which I did try in the Theme Options Custom Code, didn't work, tried in the Header JS code for s&g, didn't work.

All plugins are up to date, WP is up to date, theme - some Roofer theme and WP Bakery = all up to date, php was updated a month or so ago (which stuff started breaking).   They have a TON of stuff (plugins) that they likely don't need or use (which I've mentioned) but you know how it is when folks build their own stuff and you need to fix it, well that is where I am at.  Please help.

Site is affordableroofingfl.com  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the dropdown menu element `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownhover-bottom animated zoomIn" role="menu">` being above its child list items in the Z axis.

This makes these underlying link elements unclickable.

Relative positioning of these `<li>` children elements "activates" the already set value of their CSS property `z-index` and they become clickable again.

**CSS** rule to fix it:

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Well, I went to add that code to fix it and looking at the site in incognito, again, it is working... maybe whatever I was able to do yesterday did in fact fix it, it just took time to "propagate"?  Either way, if it happens again, I will try this.  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it was due to the clearing of the CSS cache of WPbakery or a plugin.